# How I can safely check if file exists in S3 bucket using go in lambda?

Tags: file, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on a service for my project that is used to synchronize Lambdas works in AWS. The idea is to write a TrackerFile module that will store structures on S3. Each time I use the tracker, I will check if there is a file with the name assigned to the called tracker.

I have no idea but how to safely check if a file with a given name exists on S3. can you show a sample piece of code that would be able to return (bool, err) where bool is True if the file exists?

Comment: You should be able to do something with HeadObject using the AWS GO SDK. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.HeadObject

Comment: what means "safely" in your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure compatibility across AWS SDK v3 and AWS SDK v2 I would recommend using both the 404 and the "NotFound" code.

```
export async function fileExistsInS3(bucket, key) {
    try {
        await s3.send(new HeadObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }));
        return { fileExists: true };
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 'NotFound' || (error['$fault'] === 'client' && error['$metadata']?.httpStatusCode === 404)) {
            return { fileExists: false };
        }
        throw error; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you have the following permissions:
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:ListBucket",

Regarding Safety, AWS just introduced strong consistency for S3

```
s3svc = s3.New(sess)
     
func keyExists(bucket string, key string) (bool, error) {
        _, err := s3svc.HeadObject(&s3.HeadObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(key),
        })
        if err != nil {
            if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
                switch aerr.Code() {            
                case "NotFound": // s3.ErrCodeNoSuchKey does not work, aws is missing this error code so we hardwire a string
                    return false, nil
                default:
                    return false, err
                }
            }
            return false, err
        }
        return true, nil
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

If you use the AWS SDK for Go V2:

```
import (
    ...
    awshttp "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/transport/http"
    ...
)

func uploaded(ctx context.Context, client *s3.Client, bucket string, key string) (bool, error) {
    _, err := client.HeadObject(ctx, &s3.HeadObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    })
    if err != nil {
        var responseError *awshttp.ResponseError
        if errors.As(err, &responseError) && responseError.ResponseError.HTTPStatusCode() == http.StatusNotFound {
            return false, nil
        }
        return false, err
    }
    return true, nil
}
```

[Handling Errors in the AWS SDK for Go V2](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/handling-errors/)

Comment: Excellent answer! Do you know how we could get an error in the HeadObject method ?

Comment: I meant, an error different to the not found

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's possible. You can explore the AWS SDK for Go V2 and check the available errors. Also, please go to this documentation to get into the new way to handle errors: [Handling Errors in the AWS SDK for Go V2](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/handling-errors/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to [get object metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.HeadObject):

```golang
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("your-region"),
})

if err != nil {
    //handle error here
}

svc := s3.New(session.Must(sess, err))
output, err := svc.HeadObject(&s3.HeadObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("bucket_name"),
    Key:    aws.String("object_key"),
})

if err != nil {
    //handle error here
}

fmt.Println(output.LastModified) //do something with metadata
```

Comment: surely this is unsafe to concurrent writes.

Comment: @mh-cbon I agree, but nobody knows what did R.Slaby mean under "safety". By the way, even if the S3 object is being written concurrently, why do you need to get its metadata concurrently?

Comment: usually you use s3 in some kind of distributed processing, depending the implementation requirement, they may compete for the same resource, hence my remark. Like you, i am unclear about what safely means in OP q.

Answer (score 1):

Just refer to AWS API S3 HeadObject method: [AWS API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html).
It will return **status code 404** in case of a **missing object**.

> A HEAD request has the same options as a GET action on an object. The
> response is identical to the GET response except that there is no
> response body. Because of this, if the HEAD request generates an
> error, it returns a generic 404 Not Found or 403 Forbidden code.

```
import (
  "context"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
  "log"
)

func IsObjectExistsInS3Bucket(bucketName string, objectKey string) bool{
  _, err := executeHeadObjectMethodOnS3Api(bucketName, objectKey)
  return ! handleErrorOnS3HeadObjectAction(bucketName, objectKey, err)
}

func executeHeadObjectMethodOnS3Api(bucketName string, objectKey string) (output *s3.HeadObjectOutput, err error){
  s3Client := getS3Client()
  return s3Client.HeadObject(context.TODO(), &s3.HeadObjectInput{
    Bucket:               aws.String(bucketName),
    Key:                  aws.String(objectKey),
  })
}

func handleErrorOnS3HeadObjectAction(bucketName, objectKey string, err error) (hit bool){
  logUnableToHeadObjectFromS3Bucket(bucketName, objectKey, err)
  return err != nil
}

func logUnableToHeadObjectFromS3Bucket(bucketName string, objectKey string, err error) {
  if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Unable to head object {%s} from S3 bucket {%s}: { %v }", objectKey, bucketName, err)
  }
}
```